How to copy this transaction, change the parmeters and send again?
I need to copy this transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9acf0ecfd6f5a320a419ad8b155208d25f666e228b955d6df7109c84f46f7425
After that, change the recipient address and the NFT ID and send again.
I don't know how to call this contract action because the ABI does not include the Transfer NFT action.
So, how can I send another NFT from my contract to another address?

You can call the function by using the ABI of the transferNft() function, that you can get by decoding the transaction:


Here's the minimal code using ethers.js:
const { ethers } = require('ethers')

const contractAddress = "0x12CA55A514345F86FA23E5aeA7817a3eb19C3926"

const transferNft_abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_tokenID",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_tokenAddress",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferNft",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/ALCHEMY_API_KEY");

const privateKey = "PRIVATE_KEY";

const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, transferNft_abi, signer);

const _to = "RECIPIENT_ADDRESS";

const _tokenID = "TOKEN_ID";

const _tokenAddress = "0xEa13C41067D8cEC447A7caddB8959Aac8CeE8a97";

contract.transferNft(_to, _tokenID, _tokenAddress).then(async (tx) => {
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log(receipt.hash);
})

But, the transaction will revert with this error:
Error: execution reverted: "Ownable: caller is not the owner"

Therefore, the function transferNft() can only be called by the owner of the contract.
